# Ubuntu sudo apt install: Apache2 is running as root, any security risk?

Tags: ubuntu, security, apache2, root, apache2.4

Ubuntu 20.04

```
sudo apt install apache2
```

Apache is running as root, any security risk?

```
ps aux | grep apache2
root      636826  0.0  0.1   7068  4984 ?        Ss   14:47   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  636827  0.0  0.1 1212028 4552 ?        Sl   14:47   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  636828  0.0  0.1 1212060 4548 ?        Sl   14:47   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
```

Comment: You are looking for [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/694036/apache-as-non-root), since it seems like you are in ubuntu

Comment: TL;DR: no, the first process needs root but then drops privileges and it's not the one accepting/processing requests.